# Imagick center text over image in specified area

Tags: php, imagick

I am using Imagick library to add text over image.
I have defined area over image `from x:280 to x:400` 
i am writing text in that area and i want to align that text in center the following code in centering text x:1 and x:400

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('white');
$draw->setFont($tffFile);

$draw->setTextAlignment(Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);
$draw->setFontSize( 14 );
$image->annotateImage($draw, 280, 80, 0, 'Hey there');
```

Comment: Could you please add any error you are receiving?

Comment: There are no errors but text is centered in overall image. i want to center text in specific area of image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For centering text within a region of interest, you would be responsible for calculating the coordinates before applying `Imagick::annotateImage`. Luckily [`Imagick::queryFontMetrics`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php) has been provided for this, and as you have observed, using `setTextAlignment` is more likely to complicate things then help.

```php
// Given a basic pseudo image.
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newPseudoImage(400, 400, 'PLASMA:');

// Let's define a ROI rectangle.
$rect = [
    'x' => 225,
    'y' => 225,
    'h' => 100,
    'w' => 100,
];

// Draw a Region-of-interest for reference.
$roi = new ImagickDraw();
$roi->setStrokeColor('RED');
$roi->setStrokeWidth(2);
$roi->setFillColor('TRANSPARENT');
$roi->rectangle($rect['x'],
                $rect['y'],
                $rect['x'] + $rect['w'],
                $rect['y'] + $rect['h']);
$image->drawImage($roi);

// Define your text-rendering context.
$ctx = new ImagickDraw();
$ctx->setFillColor('WHITE');
$ctx->setFontSize( 14 );

// Query who it will render with the image stack.
$metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($ctx, 'Hey there');

// Adjust starting x,y as needed to meet your requirements.
$offset = [
    'x' => $rect['x'] + $rect['w'] / 2 - $metrics['textWidth'] / 2,
    'y' => $rect['y'] + $rect['h'] / 2 + $metrics['textHeight'] / 2 + $metrics['descender'],
];
// Draw text.
$image->annotateImage($ctx,
                      $offset['x'],
                      $offset['y'],
                      0,
                      'Hey there');
// Write to disk.
$image->writeImage('output.png');
```

[image: output]

Things get a bit more complicated with word-wrapping, and content with mixed typefaces.